# Possible to use VBA to count the number of in-line pictures in multiple tables?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Trying to nail down some code that will automatically resize in-line pictures in tables throughout the document based on the quantity of pictures in each table. A document can have anywhere from 1 to > 10 separate reports, and my end goal is to get each separate report to fit on one page. Thus, if there's only one picture in the first report, I would resize it to 75%, if there are two pictures in the second report I would resize both of those to ~60% (while still keeping the first report's picture at 75%), and so on. Each report has 2 separate tables, and the pictures are always in row 2 of the 2nd table in the report.

Right now my code (shown) changes all the pictures in the report to one specific size. I have no issues counting the total quantity of pictures in the overall document using .InlineShapes.Count, and even the total number of tables using ActiveDocument.Tables.Count, but I can't figure out how to reference only the quantity of pictures in each table. I've tried looping through all the tables in the document, but any time I try to count the number of pictures in the table, it always returns the total quantity in the document.

```
Sub resize()
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument
    For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
        With .InlineShapes(i)
            .ScaleHeight = 45
            .ScaleWidth = 45
        End With
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Tables(t).Range.InlineShapes` really returns all the shapes in the document? That shouldn't happen...

Comment: Hi Tomalak, thanks for the response. I haven't worked with tables in VBA before so I was only using ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count. I did a quick test with your suggestion and it returned the correct number of shapes. I will continue playing with it today and will give and updated response later. Thanks again

Comment: If you've managed to do what you want, you can share the code and a short paragraph of explanation (i.e. answer your own question). This is actively encouraged on this site!

Answer (score 0):

Had to work through some compile errors, but the below code is what has been working for the last couple hours. It starts at the first table in the document, counts the number of shapes in that table, and resizes the shape(s) to a different scale that is dependent upon the number of shapes in the table. It continues looping through all the tables in the document until completion. Thanks to Tomalak for the nudge in the right direction.

```
Sub Dependent_Resize()

Dim t As Table
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
    Set t = ActiveDocument.Tables(i)
    j = t.Range.InlineShapes.Count
    If j = 0 Then
    ElseIf j = 1 Then
        With t.Range.InlineShapes(j)
            .ScaleHeight = 75
            .ScaleWidth = 75
        End With
    ElseIf j = 2 Then
        For k = 1 To j
         With t.Range.InlineShapes(k)
            .ScaleHeight = 60
            .ScaleWidth = 60
        End With
        Next k
    ElseIf j > 2 Then
        For k = 1 To j
        With t.Range.InlineShapes(k)
            .ScaleHeight = 45
            .ScaleWidth = 45
        End With
        Next k
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Option Explicit` can help with compile errors (Option Explicit should be at the top of the module before any Declarations), also your code can be simplified:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const LARGE_IMG As Long = 75
Private Const MEDIUM_IMG As Long = 60
Private Const SMALL_IMG As Long = 45

Sub dependentResize()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim scaleTo As Long
    Dim ilShape As InlineShape

    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
        With ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Range
            Select Case .InlineShapes.Count
                Case 1
                    scaleTo = LARGE_IMG
                Case 2
                    scaleTo = MEDIUM_IMG
                Case Else
                    scaleTo = SMALL_IMG
            End Select

            For Each ilShape In .InlineShapes
                With ilShape
                    .ScaleHeight = scaleTo
                    .ScaleWidth = scaleTo
                End With
            Next
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```